# symfony/skeleton logged in User persisted in session, but not available in getUser()

Tags: symfony, web-services, authentication, symfony-4.2

I've set up a simple `symfony/skeleton` application that contains user entity and authentication.
When after successful authentication I call a route that contains the following code:

```
public function index(Security $security)
{
   $username = $security->getUser()->getUsername();
```

This results in an error:

```
Call to a member function getUsername() on null
```

So obviously the security component does not now about the currently logged in user.
The session however does contain the current UsernamePasswordToken (I checked using dump).

The same code works fine when I use `website-skeleton`.
What is missing in skeleton?

My firewall is setup like that:

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        anonymous: true
        logout:
            path: ^/user/logout
        json_login:
            check_path: /user/login
```

Comment: Well for one thing the skeleton does not even include the security bundle.  Of course you must have loaded it otherwise Security would not be available.  I'm not familiar with json_login.  I assume you are following: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/json_login_setup.html ? Did you define your own User object?

Comment: Security bundle is installed, created the user using the maker bundle. I followed the json_login setup you mentioned.

Comment: I'd have to setup a test case.  Sometimes I run into problems with the [EquatableInterface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50584730/no-error-and-no-user-in-session-after-login-form-is-validated-in-symfony-4/50586510#50586510).  You might also check the website-skeleton version of security.yaml.  If you are willing to post your complete skeleton app to github I'd be willing to take a look.

Comment: I've compared both `security.yaml` files. They are identical.

Comment: I'm going to setup a minimal project and upload it to github.

Comment: Ok, building a minimal project lead to success. So one of my dependencies must somehow introduce problems. I'm using code generated by the [openapi-generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator), I'll look into that component.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the authenticated user from a controller that extends `AbstractController` just by using `$this->getUser();`.

Comment: Okay, what about `$security->getToken()->getUser();` ?

Comment: this returns the string `anon.`

Comment: So, Symfony consider that you're authenticate as anonymous, and that's why you can't retrieve an User. Have you followed the [Symfony tutorial](https://symfony.com/doc/master/security/json_login_setup.html) about `json_login` ? Don't know if you have already setup one but maybe missing an [User provider](https://symfony.com/doc/master/security/user_provider.html) ?